# Difference between UUID and a Generator using python

Tags: python, uuid

I have been using python for some days and found about the uuid module and it has different ways to generate uuids.

```
uuid.uuid1()
uuid.uuid3()
uuid.uuid4()
uuid.uuid5()
```

what is the difference between these and what should I use to generate unique string?

Comment: Did you try the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1). It is really clear on the difference. I short: they use different algorithms to generate the UUIDs.